# How to warp a mesh to target mesh using openCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, mesh, morphing

I want to warp a meshed image to another meshed image.

[image]

 I have meshed the picture with storage points and edges in CvSubdiv2D.

 How do I start warping to a target meshed image?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I have tried to warp whole image. I don't know how to warp every triangle to target triangle.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use 'piecewise affine warp' google it, there are a lot of code in web.

For instance:

1. https://github.com/t0nyren/piecewiseAffine
2. https://github.com/cxcxcxcx/imgwarp-opencv

Comment: Some problem about that. I want to do affine within several stage. How can I implement it?

Comment: Not getting you, can you explain please ?